# Corporate - contact names

Tags: contacts

How/ where can I add the contact name for a business?

I am about to send out an email to our corporate partners but I cannot personalise it as I do not know where to add their name in their business details.  I do not want to set up a 'new' individual to then attach to each corporate as this then increases the number of contacts on the database significantly.

Comment: Hi Dawn, first of all could you state the CMS you are using and what version of CiviCRM. Secondly, I have no clue what you are asking, can you provide a little more detail with perhaps an example?

Answer (score 3):

Adding an individual to the database and connecting it via a relationship to the organisation would be the coherent "CiviCRM-way" to do it. You should consider using this approach as a lot of CiviCRM's business logic is focussed around it (e.g. greetings, online forms etc.).

If you still want to stick to an "organizations-only-approach", you could simply add one or more custom fields for organisations and enter all relevant infoamtion (such as first and last name) in those fields.